# How to peek and test whether the next character is a digit?

Tags: macros, citing, journal-publishing

Background story: The Journal of Functional Programming has [its own LaTeX class](ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/jfp-cls/jfp1.cls) and we would like to use `\citet` (as in `natbib`). Unfortunately the class file is not compatible with `natbib` and they did not provide the style file for `biblatex` (which implements the `natbib` mode). In short, I want a magical `jfphack.sty` such that the following LaTeX document produces "Apple & Orange (9999)".

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{jfp1}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{jfphack}

\title{}
\author{}
\affil{}
\email{}
\begin{document}

\citet{test1} % want "Apple & Orange (9999)"

\bibliographystyle{jfp}
\bibliography{test}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{test1,
  title={Secret of the {U}niverse},
  author={Angry Apple and Outraged Orange},
  journal={nowhere},
  year={9999}
}
\end{filecontents}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I came up with the following hacky `.sty` file and updated the question. In general I am happy except for `\@addendparen` (and `\@ifnextdigit`). Is there a way to simplify them?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{jfphack}
\def\@ifnextdigit#1#2{%
  \@ifnextchar0{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar1{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar2{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar3{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar4{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar5{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar6{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar7{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar8{#1}%
  {\@ifnextchar9{#1}%
  {#2}}}}}}}}}}}
\def\@addendparenx#1{#1\@addendparen}
\def\@addendparen{\@ifnextdigit{\@addendparenx})}
\def\@removeendcomma#1, {#1}
\newif\if@outerparen \@outerparentrue
\def\@cite#1#2{\if@tempswa#2\else\if@outerparen(#1)\else#1\fi\fi\@outerparentrue}
\def\citet{\@outerparenfalse\def\citename##1{\@removeendcomma##1 (\@addendparen}\@internalcite}
\let\citep\cite
\let\citeyearpar\shortcite
```

Comment: Welcome! Why? If you are submitting to the journal, they won't accept the hackery. If you are not, there's no reason to use their class.

Comment: @cfr Our current draft using `natbib` was already accepted, and the reviewers seemed to be happy about the typesetting except for a broken section title due to incompatibilities. My hack would solve the problem while preserving the typesetting of the rest. I'm aware that they might not accept the hack so I'm trying to make it more elegant. :-)

Comment: Do reviewers care about typesettting in your discipline? In mine, the copy-editor cares *after* the paper is accepted, but before it is published. The reviewers just care about the content. (Provided it is reasonable.) Indeed, usually journals ask for different formatting at the review stage (e.g. double-spaced) than is used in the final version (e.g. single-spaced).

Comment: You should at least check with your copy editor before investing time and effort into this.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the suggestion. I just checked with editors and they are fine as long as I follow the style guide (which I do).

Comment: Whether or not the journal cares about hackery is highly field-specific.  In mine, none do.

Comment: Do you know for sure that what follows the (first) call to `\@addendparen` is an integer number?  Must leading zeros be kept?  If not, simply `\def\@addendparen{\bgroup\afterassignment\@addendparen@\count0= }\def\@addendparen@{\the\count0)\egroup}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the citation received is

```
\citename{Apple \& Orange, }9999
```

So it's a matter of redefining `\citename` when necessary.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  title={Secret of the {U}niverse},
  author={Angry Apple and Outraged Orange},
  journal={nowhere},
  year={9999}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{jfp}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage{jfphack}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@citet
\let\citet\cite
\xpretocmd{\cite}{\@citetfalse}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\citet}{\@citettrue}{}{}
\newcommand{\citetcitename}[1]{%
  \citet@removecomma#1\@nil
  \afterassignment\citet@year\count@
}
\def\citet@year{(\the\count@)}
\def\@cite#1#2{%
  \if@tempswa
    #2%
  \else
    \if@citet
      \begingroup
      \let\citename\citetcitename
      #1%
      \endgroup
    \else
     (#1)%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\citet@removecomma#1, \@nil{#1~}
\makeatother

\title{}
\author{}
\affil{}
\email{}
\begin{document}

\cite{test1} % want "Apple & Orange (9999)"

\citet{test1}
\bibliographystyle{jfp}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

This assumes the year is present.

Comment: Thanks. This is great! I also want to give @bruno-le-floch credit for pointing out `\afterassignment` in a comment to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the @ifnextdigit very much by using futurelet

```
\def\@ifnextdigit#1{\def\@doit{#1}\futurelet\next\@finish}
\def\@finish{\ifcat3\next\expandafter\@doit\fi}
```

To use it, you place whatever command is to be executed on finding a digit as the argument to @ifnextdigit. It is then stored in \@doit. Then we use futurelet to peek at the next token after this macro is expanded, and store it in \next. Then we use the ifcat test to check if it has the category code of a number, and if it does, execute \@doit.

Comment: `\ifcat3\next` does not distinguish digits from punctuation characters for example.

Comment: Why would there be punctuation in the beggining of a parentheses block that should make that an issue?

Comment: @jfbu is basically pointing out that numbers have category code 12 like many other tokens. Hence, you are not actually checking if `\next` is a number, but if `\next` has catcode 'other'. Apart from that I really like the approach. If there only would be an expandable test for numbers :)

Comment: @Ruben to be honest I hardly looked at the question here (apologies to @AGoldMan) but yes there is an expandable test for numbers `\ifnum 9<1#1 ` will do the trick if `#1` is token to be tested, however it does not work with a `\next` in place of such a  `#1`. If expansion of `#1` can be dangerous (i.e. contains conditional tokens for example), then `\ifnum 9<\detokenize{1#1} ` should work, and attention to the mandatory space token at the end I have inserted to close the number.

Comment: (in my comment above I am naturally talking about testing for a _digit token_, not a full number, then one can organize this on successive tokens, but for a precise answer, one needs the context to be clearly stated and the original question looks a bit vague)

Comment: @AGoldMan Thanks for your solution. This greatly simplifies my ugly hack. I picked the other one as the answer because if we exploit the context (that is, it should be a _reasonable_ year) then `\afterassignment` seems simpler. If we decide to do the manual parsing, I personally prefer @jfbu's solution which works in more general situations.

Comment: @favonia glad i got you the help you needed