# \let-number checker

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

Is there a safe way to check if some macro input is a number that was `\let` to a number? I.e. suppose we said `\let\foo=1`, is it possible to define a macro `\isnumber` that determines if `\foo` was a number? (`\isnumber\foo{true}{false}`)

Comment: A token `\let` to a digit doesn't fit the syntax for a `<number>`, so it cannot be used in the context of `\ifnum`

Comment: @egreg - So the question is more about the `\let` part overall. I rephrase the question then. Thanks!

Comment: @Ruben Something `\let` to a number is not expandable.

Comment: Do you plan to have mixtures such as `2\foo3`? Besides, is this just an intellectual teaser or you have some use case in mind?

Comment: @egreg - no mixtures needed and no intellectuality for intellectualities sake intended :) There is a question here where it could be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323311/how-to-peek-and-test-whether-the-next-character-is-a-digit

Comment: `\ifx1\foo y\else\ifx2\foo y\else\ifx3\foo y\else n\fi\fi\fi` tests if it is ifx equal to 1 2 or 3, and could be extended for 0-9

Comment: a command name let to a digit is not a macro and is not expandable , so I don't think the current tags are right, perhaps tex-core.

Comment: is your question limited to macros `\let` to a digit token or do you also consider macros `\let` to a `\count`, as "number" seems to imply ? or possibly also chardef tokens ? (b.t.w. meaning does not distinguish `\foo` from `\bar` after `\newcount\foo\let\bar\foo`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of exhibiting my poor memory, I am recalling that the question has changed from its original incarnation.  Here, I use David's idea to try to reconstruct an answer to your original question, which gets around the limitation that `\let` variables cannot be used in `\ifnum` context.

The `\testdigit` macro tests the following token as to whether it is an actual digit, a `\def`ed number, **or a `\let` digit**.  The only ambiguous result, if you wish to call it that is if the next token has been `\def`ed to a multi-digit alphanumeric combination.  In that case, the test is performed on the first token of the `\def`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\thedigit#1{%
\ifx0#10\else\ifx1#11\else\ifx2#12\else
\ifx3#13\else\ifx4#14\else\ifx5#15\else
\ifx6#16\else\ifx7#17\else\ifx8#18\else
\ifx9#19\else\detokenize\expandafter{#1}%
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}

\def\testdigit#1{\if\relax\ifnum9>1\thedigit#1\relax F\fi\relax T\else F\fi}

\begin{document}

1 \testdigit1

2 \testdigit\section

3 \def\zzz{5}\testdigit\zzz

4 \def\zzz{56}\testdigit\zzz

5 \let\zzz7\testdigit\zzz

6 \testdigit t

7 \testdigit\relax

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is a useful distinction in many cases but probably this does what is asked:

[image]

as seen in the first test it is true for both implicit and explicit digit characters, they could be distinguished if needed. (For example comparing the output of `\string`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\isdigit#1{%
\if y\ifx0#1y\else\ifx1#1y\else\ifx2#1y\else
\ifx3#1y\else\ifx4#1y\else\ifx5#1y\else
\ifx6#1y\else\ifx7#1y\else\ifx8#1y\else
\ifx9#1y\else n%
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi}


1 \isdigit1{1 yes}{1 no}

2 \isdigit\section{section yes}{section no}

3 \def\zzz{5}\isdigit\zzz{def 5 yes}{def 5 no}

4 \let\zzz7\isdigit\zzz{let 7 yes}{let 7 no}

5 \isdigit t{t yes}{t no}

\end{document}
```